# $f(x_1)=g(x_2)$ for any $x=(x_1,x_2)$; then $f$ and $g$ are constant functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations

$f,g$ are real functions.

$f(x_1)=g(x_2)$ for any $x=(x_1,x_2)$

$x\in\mathbb R^2$.

Prove that $g,f$ are constants.

My tries:

It seems really easy.

Just simply take $y=(x_1,y_2)$. We have, for any $x_2,y_2$:

$$g(x_2)=f(x_1)=g(y_2).$$

That is $g$ is constant. Similarly $f$ is constant.

I am not sure my logics is correct?

Comment: pretty good, just make sure you also do the complimentary step to show f is constant

Comment: This is a very strange problem. Are you sure you interpreted it correctly?

Comment: @ElliotG Thank you for your comment. What do you mean by weird? It seems too easy?

Comment: Option: 1)f(x)=g(x) for all x, implies f=g; 2) f(x)=g(a), a fixed, for all x, hence f=const.